# How to Find the Weblogic bit version?

Tags: weblogic

Once the weblogic is installed, say weblogic 10.3.5 is installed in unix. Do you know where to check, whether the installed weblogic is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1.View the config.xml file of domain home

The config.xml file is located at:

```
$WL_HOME/user_projects/domains/domain/config
```

Once you open the config.xml file , you will see an entry od Domain version.
This is the same as weblogic version.

2.Using wlst

Go to $WL_HOME/common/bin

Run ./wlst.sh

```
wls:/offline>version
```

WebLogic Server 10.3 SP0 Fri Jul 25 16:30:05 EDT 2008 1137967

This shows the weblogic version

3.Go to $WL_HOME/server/bin

```
./setWLSEnv.sh    Then run 'java weblogic.version'
```

It will give you the weblogic version

Comment: This answers a completely different question, as it finds the version (i.e. 10.3.2.0), and not if it is 64 or 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Version of **WEBLOGIC** it depends of the version of **JVM** is installed and running. **WEBLOGIC** not determines version, is Java Virtual Machine that say who version it is.

The correct *env* variable for **WEBLOGIC** installed *path* is **$WEBLOGIC_HOME**.

In **WEBLOGIC SERVER 10.3.4.0** in **$WEBLOGIC_HOME/user_projects/domains/$HOSTNAME/config/config.xml** you can see the version of **JVM** that it's configured on:

```
<server>
    <name>Admin</name>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
    <server-start>
      <java-home>/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24</java-home>
    </server-start>
  </server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic is coming as a **GENERIC** distribution. It is a Java program running on top of a VM so there is no need for Weblogic-64bit or Weblogic-32bit versions.

On the other hand, the JVM running Weblogic must be either 32bit or 64bit depending on the architecture.

Comment: if the weblogic is installed on 32 bit jdk, it should be 32 bit version, if it is installed on 64 bit jdk, then 64 bit weblogic should be installed. Thats what i found out.

Comment: There is only ONE distro of weblogic, its GENERIC - i.e. arch. independent. See here :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html